# Spring and Hibernate Runtime error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, runtime

Below error is seen on my eclipse.  I am just trying to save a terminalgroup object and was getting an error about TerminalGroupImpl not found.  So I created a TerminalGroupImpl.java to be a hibernate file that has the @Entity for the terminal_group table.  I have a TerminalGroupDaoHibernate.java file that using the TerminalGroupImpl.class to execute queries on the terminal_group table.

Please if someone can tell me what is wrong with my code and/or what I can do to figure out what is wrong?

Error

```
Invalid property 'terminalGroupDaoHibernate' of bean class
[com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.TerminalGroupServiceImpl]: 
Bean property 'terminalGroupDaoHibernate' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. 
Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml file:

```
<!-- Terminal Group Service -->
<bean id="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.TerminalGroupService"
    class="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.TerminalGroupServiceImpl">
 <property name="terminalGroupDao"   
ref="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.dao.TerminalGroupDao"/>
 <property name="terminalGroupComponentDao" 
ref="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.dao.TerminalGroupComponentDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.TerminalGroupImpl"
    class="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.TerminalGroupImpl" abstract="true">
    <property name="terminalGroupDaoHibernate" 
ref="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.dao.TerminalGroupDaoHibernate"/>
</bean>

<bean id="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.dao.TerminalGroupDao"
    class="com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.dao.TerminalGroupDaoHibernate">
        <property name="messageService" ref="com.ccadllc.dac.messaging.MessagingService" /> 
</bean>

under hibernate.annotated.classes:                  
<value>com.ccadllc.dac.model.consumer.terminalgroups.TerminalGroupImpl</value>
```

TerminalGroupServiceImpl.java

```
Getter/Setter in TerminalGroupServiceImpl.java:
private TerminalGroupDao terminalGroupHibernateDao;
 /**
 * @param TerminalGroupHibernateDao The TerminalGroupHibernateDao to set.
 */
@Required
@Transactional
public void setTerminalGroupHibernateDao(final TerminalGroupDao terminalGroupHibernateDao)
{
    this.terminalGroupHibernateDao = terminalGroupHibernateDao;
}

@Required
@Transactional
public TerminalGroupDao getTerminalGroupHibernateDao()
{
    return terminalGroupHibernateDao;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set terminalGroupDaoHibernate property instead of terminalGroupHibernateDao.

Answer (score 0):

The property you have defined in the xml is "terminalGroupDaoHibernate", but the setter in your service impl's name is "setTerminalGroupHibernateDao". There is typo error. The setter name should be "setTerminalGroupDaoHibernate"

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the @Required annotation on a getter. Also, in your bean xml, you use the property name `terminalGroupDao` but your setter has the name `setTerminalGroupHibernateDao` rather than `setTerminalGroupDao`.